# Onelogin with Django: Receiving a GET when I would expect a POST

Tags: django, single-sign-on, saml, onelogin

I followed the tutorial to deploy [single sign-on with OneLogin over my Django app](https://developers.onelogin.com/saml/python) and when I click on the login button, the request I receive from OneLogin is not a POST as expected, but a GET. Then the library raises a OneLogin_Saml2_Error: "SAML Response not found, Only supported HTTP_POST Binding". At this moment I am stuck since the documentation doesn't give any useful information on this, so I would welcome any tips.

Comment: Hi Pablo, an HTTP_POST must arrive to the SP ACS URL. Go to the OneLogin   connector and verivy in the configuration tab that the settings are correct. Also verify that the prepare request method of the django app is correct.  If you install SAML Tracer Firefox's plugin, you can verify if the SAMLResponse is sent as a POST to the right endpoint.

Comment: Thanks @smartin for your tip. In the end, it turns out the problem was a combined error on my side and (likely) Onelogin's side as well. On the one hand, our load balancer was redirecting all http traffic to https, and that was deflecting the initial request before I could even see it reach my app. On the other hand, Onelogin takes the 302 redirect and turns a POST into a GET request, for reasons I do not yet understand.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, it turns out the problem was a combined error on my side and (likely) Onelogin's side as well. On the one hand, our load balancer was redirecting all http traffic to https, and that was deflecting the initial request before I could even see it reach my app. On the other hand, Onelogin takes the 302 redirect and turns a POST into a GET request, for reasons I do not yet understand.